# Program output as an argument of another program

Tags: linux, unix, bash

I'm reading [Unix Programming Environment](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013937681X).There is a sample program

```
echo "time is 'date'"
```

with output as

```
time is {current time}
```

But in ubuntu's bash shell it is not giving output as expected.It prints whole line as it is

```
 time is 'date'
```

Why is that?
and Is it okay to read outdated book to learn Linux OS?

Comment: You might consider migrating this question to unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the following instead:

```
echo "time is `date`"
```

` (backtick) instead of ' (apostrophe)

The Unix/Linux foundation is the same, but a lot of utilities change over time so their options differ widely over time.  Even between flavors they differ.  So an older book is usually fine as most things will still work and are still accurate.  A newer book would give you better use of newer features that didn't exist in the old days.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `echo "time is $(date)"` to avoid confusing single quote with backstick.